# Increasing the size of the field generated from jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

The following tag :

```
<input type="text" class="timepicker" name="SelectedTime" id="timepicker"  />
```

with the help of `jquery` :

```
/* jQuery timepicker
 * replaces a single text input with a set of pulldowns to select hour, minute, and am/pm
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2007 Jason Huck/Core Five Creative (http://www.corefive.com/)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) 
 * and GPL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php) licenses.
 *
 * Version 1.0
 */

(function($){
    jQuery.fn.timepicker = function(){
        this.each(function(){
            // get the ID and value of the current element
            var i = this.id;
            var v = $(this).val();

            // the options we need to generate
            var hrs = new Array('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12');
            var mins = new Array('00','15','30','45');
            var ap = new Array('am','pm');

            // default to the current time
            var d = new Date;
            var h = d.getHours();
            var m = d.getMinutes();
            var p = (h >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am');

            // adjust hour to 12-hour format
            if(h > 12) h = h - 12;

            // round minutes to nearest quarter hour
            for(mn in mins){
                if(m <= parseInt(mins[mn])){
                    m = parseInt(mins[mn]);
                    break;
                }
            }

            // increment hour if we push minutes to next 00
            if(m > 45){
                m = 0;

                switch(h){
                    case(11):
                        h += 1;
                        p = (p == 'am' ? 'pm' : 'am');
                        break;

                    case(12):
                        h = 1;
                        break;

                    default:
                        h += 1;
                        break;
                }
            }

            // override with current values if applicable
            if(v.length == 7){
                h = parseInt(v.substr(0,2));
                m = parseInt(v.substr(3,2));
                p = v.substr(5);
            }

            // build the new DOM objects
            var output = '';

            output += '<select id="h_' + i + '" class="h timepicker">';             
            for(hr in hrs){
                output += '<option value="' + hrs[hr] + '"';
                if(parseInt(hrs[hr]) == h) output += ' selected';
                output += '>' + hrs[hr] + '</option>';
            }
            output += '</select>';

            output += '<select id="m_' + i + '" class="m timepicker">';             
            for(mn in mins){
                output += '<option value="' + mins[mn] + '"';
                if(parseInt(mins[mn]) == m) output += ' selected';
                output += '>' + mins[mn] + '</option>';
            }
            output += '</select>';              

            output += '<select id="p_' + i + '" class="p timepicker">';             
            for(pp in ap){
                output += '<option value="' + ap[pp] + '"';
                if(ap[pp] == p) output += ' selected';
                output += '>' + ap[pp] + '</option>';
            }
            output += '</select>';              

            // hide original input and append new replacement inputs
            $(this).attr('type','hidden').after(output);
        });

        $('select.timepicker').change(function(){
            var i = this.id.substr(2);
            var h = $('#h_' + i).val();
            var m = $('#m_' + i).val();
            var p = $('#p_' + i).val();
            var v = h + ':' + m + p;
            $('#' + i).val(v);
        });

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.timepicker').timepicker();
});


/* SVN: $Id: jquery.timepicker.js 456 2007-07-16 19:09:57Z Jason Huck $ */
```

gives out :

[image]

How can I increase the size the `input fields` ? I tried doing like this :

```
<input type="text" class="timepicker" name="SelectedTime" 
   id="timepicker" style="height:40px; font-size:20px"  />
```

but the output is same.

Comment: look at generated html-code with browser console

Comment: it is working fine http://jsbin.com/nakidaka/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code hides the actual input fields and replaces them with select, with class name "timepicker" which you can use to control the styling.

Apply the following css in your code:

```
.timepicker{
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```